# How can I resolve the 'Error executing command' message while building a Docker container

Tags: php, node.js, laravel, docker, dockerfile

I am doing a docker-compose build and I am getting the following message

```
#0 3.997 ## Installing packages required for setup: lsb-release gnupg...
#0 3.997 + apt-get install -y lsb-release gnupg > /dev/null 2>&1
#0 12.91 Error executing command, exiting
------
failed to solve: executor failed running [/bin/sh -c curl -fsSL      https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_18.x | bash - && apt-get install -y nodejs]: exit code: 1
```

here is my dockerfile with php, nodejs:

```
FROM php:8.2-fpm

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    apt-utils\
    libpq-dev\
    libpng-dev\
    libzip-dev\
    libjpeg-dev\
    zip unzip \
    git && \
    docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql && \
    docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-jpeg && \
    docker-php-ext-install -j$(nproc) gd zip && \
    docker-php-ext-install bcmath && \
    apt-get clean && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /tmp/* /var/tmp/*

 COPY ./.docker/app/php.ini /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/php.ini

 COPY app /var/www/app
 COPY bootstrap /var/www/bootstrap
 COPY config /var/www/config
 COPY database /var/www/database
 COPY public /var/www/public
 COPY resources /var/www/resources
 COPY routes /var/www/routes
 COPY storage /var/www/storage
 COPY artisan /var/www/artisan
 COPY package.json /var/www/package.json
 COPY vite.config.js /var/www/vite.config.js

 COPY composer.* ./

 RUN curl -fsSL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_18.x | bash - && \
    apt-get install -y nodejs

 RUN npm install -g npm

 ENV COMPOSER_ALLOW_SUPERUSER=1
 RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- \
    --filename=composer \
    --install-dir=/usr/local/bin

RUN composer install \
    --no-interaction \
    --no-plugins\
    --no-suggest \
    --no-scripts \
    --no-autoloader \
    --prefer-dist

RUN composer dump-autoload --no-scripts --optimize && \
    chown -R root:www-data /var/www && \
    chmod 755 -R /var/www && \
    chmod -R 775 /var/www/storage && \
    chmod -R 775 /var/www/bootstrap/cache

WORKDIR /var/www
```

I tried to install different versions of node but it did not help. I also tried clearing the cache and rebuilding the containers and that didn't help either. Tried installing with gnupg and that didn't solve my problem either.

Comment: Well, don't redirect the error to `/dev/null`, write it somewhere where you can look at it.